# Application uses anonymous authentication even though it is disabled in IIS

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication

I have a diagnostic web application hosted in IIS7 that has Windows Authentication enabled and Anonymous auth disabled. This application generated some kind of a report where it includes information about what kind of authentication was used to view the site. Every time I browse to this site I get a message that I connected using Anonymous authentication which for me is unbelievable. The report works fine (tested on other machine) and the fact is that I do not get a credentials popup. How is this possible and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm not knocking your diagnostic application, but it may be worth looking at the IIS logs (or indeed switching them on for your site) to see what IIS thinks is going on. If you're not familiar with IIS logs, I'd suggest writing them in Microsoft format (at least while you're sorting this problem). One of the key fields you get is the user id. If you really are hitting the pages anonymously, this id will be the id you configured to field anonymous requests. Otherwise, it will normally be the calling user's id (at least in a simple scenario).

Second, how many sites are you running? Are you sure you're going in through the expected site? Or maybe you're hitting the default site instead?

Third, bear in mind that authentication can be set at the site level but anso at the page level. Are you sure one isn't overriding the other?